# Disabling background task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

My app handles raw push notifications, but it processes them differently when it's running on foreground or as a background task.

Right now when the application starts I check if there's a bg task registered and if it is then I unregistered the task and let the app handle push notifications and when the app is being closed or suspended I re-register the bg task.

This approach doesn't seem very clean to me. Is there a better way to pause the background task when the app is active or a way to check application's state from `IBackgroundTask`?

Comment: woah, what's going on with the down votes?

Comment: Quite an easy solution - can you provide a flag in *LocalSettings* which is responsible for UI state? Then let your BTask check the flag and decide if to perform work. The UI only changes the flag in settings, you don't have to unregister BTask then.

Comment: @Romasz would you care to make you comment an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please check if your notification is passed to *BackgroundTask*, as [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709907.aspx#create_a_function_to_handle_the_push_notification_event):

> When your app's cloud service sends a notification to Windows, your app has the opportunity to intercept and handle that notification before it displays a toast, updates a tile or badge, or delivers a raw notification to a background task.

In case you have running app, you should be able to intercept the notification before it goes to background task or elsewhere.

In case you want to differentiate the background task's job, depending on UI, you can  provide a flag in *LocalSettings* which is responsible for UI state, then let your BTask check the flag and decide if to perform work.

The UI only changes the flag in settings, you don't have to unregister BTask then.

Comment: That's what I thought, but what happens right now is: my app gets the raw notification, handles it and only then I get a toast from my background task. It might have something to do with the fact that the app gets unfocused right after the raw notification is handled. Now when I know that the foreground should be able to intercept the event I will need to play with it.

Comment: Oh man, thanks again. I found exactly what was wrong. I was missing `e.Cancel = true;` on my UI's push notification received event.